# How to custom linkify text in android

Tags: android, linkify

In my android app there is a page where I have to display a text - "Terms & Conditions"
On clicking this text we need to open a url in the browser 
Please tell me how to achieve this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

simple use `setonItemclickListener` for your `textview`. And in the click event create an intent to next activity which contains the `webView` or use default `Action_VIEW` which opens default browser.

Comment: hi dude i have set the bulk of text to the textview. I need to open the link when the certain text clicked. how can i achieve this

Comment: setOnItemClickListener is not part of TextView.

Answer (score 1):

May be its helpful to you.

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
text.settext("Your text with url");
text.setLinkTextColor(Color.BLUE); // color whatever u want
Linkify.addLinks(text, Linkify.ALL);
```

Comment: Hi kalpana! thnaks for the answer but in this code where is the url that I want to open up in my browser

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
text.settext("Your text with url means your text value");// text having url
text.setLinkTextColor(Color.BLUE); // color whatever u want
Linkify.addLinks(text, Linkify.ALL);
```

Hi ankit you will set the text of yours in text view it automatically recognizes the url part of your text and creates the link to that url. if you have still any query feel free to ask :)